# Sampling from posterior distribution of custom density in PyMC3

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I am trying to get the predictive distribution from my model, which happens to be a custom defined probability. Which happens to be a mixture of Normals.

```
with RE2:
    trace = pm.variational.sample_vp(v_params, draws=5000)


trigger.set_value(triggers_test)
cc.set_value(cc_test)
y_output.set_value(np.zeros((len(y_test),)))

ppc = pm.sample_ppc(trace, model=RE2, samples=2000)  

y_pred = ppc['R'].mean(axis=0)[:,None]
```

However, I get the error: `AttributeError: 'DensityDist' object has no attribute 'random'`. Is there a way to sample from the distribution? I am able to get the trace, and I can play around with this a bit, but I'm hoping that there is something better.

If it helps:

```
R = pm.DensityDist('R', logp_nmix(mus, stds, pi), observed=y_output)
```

I was able to get the posterior properly (i.e. `pm.sample_ppc` working) when pm.DensityDist was applied to a latent variable rather than a observed variable.